# How render ID2D1Bitmap with transparent where is white

Tags: directx, transparent, jpeg, direct2d

Hello i am writing something like file reader.
One of this features is to read images.some images are JPG format.
this images are white in the region where it should be transparent(because jpg does not support alpha channel).
In other words i need to render with Direct2d images in a way that where there is white there should be transparent.
Any suggestions?
thanks
Przemek

Answer (score 1):

The two most obvious options:

- Upon reading the .jpg file, convert it to 32 bit with an alpha layer manually, then enable *alpha testing* to discard those pixels.
- Use a pixel shader that does a `discard` for every white pixel